# Mailcore2 in Swift after update Xcode to Xcode8 and Swift3 doesn't work

Tags: smtp, swift3, mailcore2

After update to swift3 and xcode8 this code does not work. Before update works fine. I can't find what's problem. I was trying update pods and run code in older version xcode but doesn't work. All works fine before apple start update to swift3.

This is a error witch is printed:

`Error sending email: Optional(Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.})`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
  smtpSession.hostname = "host"
  smtpSession.username = "username"
  smtpSession.password = "pass"
  smtpSession.port = 465
  smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.saslPlain
  smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
  smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
     if data != nil {
        if let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
           print("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
        }
     }
  }

  let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
  builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "tadeuszek666@gmail.com", mailbox: "tadeuszek666@gmail.com")]
  builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "jan.fryderyk12@o2.pl", mailbox: "jan.fryderyk12@o2.pl")
  builder.header.subject = "temat nowej wiadomosci"
  builder.htmlBody = "cialo wiadomosci"

  let rfc822Data = builder.data()
  let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperation(with: rfc822Data)

  sendOperation?.start { (error) -> Void in
     if (error != nil) {
        print("Error sending email: \(error)")

     } else {
        print("Successfully sent email!")

        //ContainerViews.tabBarViewController?.selectedIndex = 0

     }
  }

 }
```